# CodeIgniter: "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Tags: php, codeigniter, mime-types, codeigniter-2

I'm experiencing a very odd upload problem. Here's the relevant view file:

```
<form action="http://localhost/index.php/temp/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="file" name="userfile"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here's my `temp` controller's `upload()` method:

```
public function upload()
{
    $config['upload_path']   = FCPATH . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    assert(file_exists($config['upload_path']) === TRUE);
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'avi|mpg|mpeg|wmv|jpg';
    $config['max_size']      = '0';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile') === FALSE)
    {
        // Some error occured
        var_dump($this->upload->display_errors('', ''));
        var_dump($_FILES);
    }
    else
    {
        // Upload successful
        var_dump($this->upload->data());
    }
}
```

When I upload an AVI video, everything works fine. When I upload, say, a WMV video, I get the following var dumps:

```
string 'The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.' (length=57)

array
  'userfile' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'wmv.wmv' (length=7)
      'type' => string 'video/x-ms-wmv' (length=14)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2333.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 83914
```

The "wmv" extension is being interpreted as the MIME type: `video/x-ms-wmv`. This should be fine since my config/mimes.php has the following:

```
'wmv' =>  array('video/x-ms-wmv', 'audio/x-ms-wmv')
```

It's a similar situation when I try uploading other files. So far, the only one that seems to work is my test AVI video.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**

One my machine, only AVI uploads. On another developer's machine, no files upload. On yet another developer's machine, all supported files upload. Are these browser or server issues?

Comment: Wonder if it's getting hung up on the file name `wmv.wmv`, try a diff file name.

Comment: is the upload size limit (php.ini) set too small for other files?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You are using Firefox, aren't you?

You could try looking at `system/libraries/Upload.php` line 199:

```
$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]);
```

Change that line to:

```
$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]); var_dump($this->file_type); die();
```

Then do upload your `.wmv` file. It would show something like `application/octet-stream` or whatever. Add that to your `mimes.php`. Hope this help =)

Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10762488/700643)

Some links:

- [CodeIgniter forum's thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/146338/)
- [Mimetype corruption in Firefox](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/15872/14863/Mimetype-corruption-in-Firefox.html)
- [Getting around IE’s MIME type mangling](http://weblog.philringnalda.com/2004/04/06/getting-around-ies-mime-type-mangling)

Comment: OK, your suggestion worked. I updated to the latest stable version of CI and noticed that the mimes.php doesn't have `wmv` anymore. So I added back the original array + application/octet-stream. Thanks!

Comment: Agree with Eric. Had to add text/plain for uploading a css file.

Comment: On codeigniter3 go to line no. 454 and add this line var_dump($this->file_type); die(); to get file type. If file type is not in your mimes.php then add it.

Comment: I'm having identical installations on localhost and online. I even tried your method and the mime type is correctly shown in the file. But I cannot upload online. The upload only works on localhost. BTW, I can upload images. But not the Excel files. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

$config["allowed_types"] ="*";

Answer (score 4):

1. Upload your .wmv file to the server using FTP/SFTP/scp/etc where you run the CodeIgniter application
2. On the server where you have uploaded the .wmv file, execute the following PHP code

   ```
   <?php
   $file_path = 'CHANGE_THIS_TO_ABSOLUTE_FILE_PATH_THAT_YOU_HAVE_UPLOADED.wmv';
   $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
   $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
   var_dump($mime);
   ?>
   ```
3. Save the code as mime.php
4. Run in the terminal - $ php mime.php
5. If it dumps any other value than you already have for wmv, append that value into wmv mime types.

Also check PHP_VERSION in other development machines. finfo_open is introduced in PHP 5.3. The development machine where upload is working may have an older version of PHP or it may have right mime type for the wmv.

Answer (score 2):

did you try using mime types instead of extensions in $config['allowed_types']?

write it like this

```
$config["allowed_types"] = "video/x-msvideo|image/jpeg|video/mpeg|video/x-ms-wmv";
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer for to Upload .doc file in CodeIgniter

Change this

```
'doc'   =>  'application/msword',
```

With this on line no 95 (`application/config/mimes.php` file)

```
'doc'   =>  array('application/vnd.ms-word','application/msword'),
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had some very similar problems with the Codeigniter's Upload Class.

The *allowed_types* doesn't seem to be working. For example, I wanted to allow .PNG images to be uploaded, but it wouldn't allow them through it's filter. I ended up investigating it further. I allowed all file types to be temporarily uploaded, I uploaded a .PNG, and then dumped the upload data (*$this->upload->data());*). For some reason, it thought the MIME type was *text/plain*! This might be related to your problem.

There are some solutions to this I found surfing some forums where you can modify/extend the class or core, but they didn't work for me --  sorry. I believe it's a Codeigniter Core bug (I think the issue has already been opened with EllisLabs). I ended up hard-coding the damn thing anyways! Well, I hope this helps you some.

Basic example/work-around,

```
//replace with your allowed MIME types
if ($_FILES['name_of_form_upload']['type'] != 'image/jpeg' && $_FILES['name_of_form_upload']['type'] != 'image/png' && $_FILES['name_of_form_upload']['type'] != 'image/gif') {
    $data['message'] = '<div class="message">That file type is not allowed!</div>';
    $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
} else {
    //run upload code
}
```

Edit: Formatting/Grammar

Comment: I don't believe it's a problem with the core. On one of the development machines, everything works as expected. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Check your mimes.php file in application/config. It should return an array of mime types e.g `return $mimes;` at end of file or `return array(.....` in start of mimes array.

Answer (score 1):

For Codeigniter 3.1.7 if you are providing a custom file name via `$config['file_name']` ensure the filename has the file extension as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in the core.. I upgraded to latest version of CI and the bug disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

if you need the simple way to solve this,there is an easy solution for it.
    open "system/libraries/Upload.php" file

```
line no 465
you will see 
if ( ! $this->is_allowed_filetype())
        {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filetype', 'debug');
            return FALSE;
        }


just make it true

    if ( ! $this->is_allowed_filetype())
            {
                $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filetype', 'debug');
                return TRUE;
            }

note : it will stop your all file type validation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change IN application\config\Mimes.php

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, but in my case the problem was a bit different than expected - it was due to the fact that the PHP config parameter open_basedir did not also contain the upload_tmp_dir (temporary upload file) path value in my Apache VirtualHost config file for the site in question, so this line of code in system/libraries/Upload.php was (silently) failing:

```
    if (in_array($ext, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'jpe', 'png', 'webp'), TRUE) && @getimagesize($this->file_temp) === FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

I removed the @ temporarily just to confirm, and sure enough, the @ was suppressing warnings that would otherwise go to my php error log and alert me to this Apache site misconfiguration. So basically the file and the code was "fine", the problem was the upload path was inaccessible.

This will not be the case for everyone, but it is certainly one possible (and likely) cause for the issue, especially for those who may have just relocated a site between hosting environments.