# Uploading .amr with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, amr

I have been trying to get .arm upload to a website built in codeigniter. I know its not a default mine type so I added it with this:

```
'amr'   =>  'audio/amr',
```

but its doesnt seem to be working with that. I also added it to the allowed types. Any idea if amr can be supported and if so what may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try looking at `system/libraries/Upload.php` line 199:
`$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]);`
Change that line to
`$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]); var_dump($this->file_type); die();`
Now you redo your uploading and see what the actual mime type the browser sent to your server.

One silly and insecure workaround I did was adding that actual mime type to mimes array. But this could change if this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762391/codeigniter-wrong-uploading-file-mime-type) get answered :)

Comment: Great answer. I did this and it show it as 'application/octet-stream' so I change it to 'amr'   =>  'application/octet-stream', and it worked perfectly. This also helped me fix another issue I was having with some mp4 not uploading. Thanks :)

Comment: I must remind you again that I don't think this workaround is safe.