# CodeIgniter: wrong uploading file mime type

Tags: php, http, codeigniter, file-upload, mime-types

Sometimes, when uploading files using `<input>` tag, I encounter problem where the file extension doesn't match with its mime type defined in `application/config/mimes.php`. For example when I upload a `.doc` file, it turns out that its mime type is actually `application/octet-stream`, not `application/msword` as expected.

I had this problem sometimes in the past. I did work around by adding `application/octet-stream` to `.doc` mime array. But is there a proper way to fix it?

I think the browser have force my file's mime type somehow. Is there any kind of HTTP header or html meta tag to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/145433/#713128) this a common problem and the solution you applied is legitimate.

Comment: Ah. Thank for the link :) Here is another one <http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/15872/14863/Mimetype-corruption-in-Firefox.html>

Answer (score 0):

It is not due to problem with codeignitor. It is due to php issue. For instance `finfo_file` function will return image with extension jpeg as image/png.

So, solution is go to `config/mimes.php` file and then add corresponding extension.

In case you do not know what is the extension behind the scene php is picking add this code to check.

```
$finfo = @finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime = @finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["myname"]['tmp_name']);
```

`$mime` will be extension which php finally returns.