# Codeigniter - Image Upload works on localhost(WAMP) but doesn't work online

Tags: php, linux, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu

I know that this question has been answered many times, but i still have trouble uploading images..

I am using codeigniter 2.1.4.
Image upload works fine on localhost, but doesn't work on remote server(linux)

I have already tried these solutions: - [Codeigniter upload file not working online but works on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572415/codeigniter-upload-file-not-working-online-but-works-on-localhost?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But it still doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```html
//Controller

function add()
 {
  if(!$this->session->userdata('is_shop_admin')) {
        $this->check_access('add');
  }
 
  if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')=='POST') {   
   $upload_data = $this->uploader->upload($_FILES);
   
   if (!isset($upload_data['error'])) {
     $category_data = array(
     'name' => htmlentities( $this->input->post('name')),
     'ordering' => htmlentities( $this->input->post('ordering')),
     'shop_id' => $this->get_current_shop()->id,
     'is_published' => 1
    );
    
    if ($this->category->save($category_data)) {
     foreach ($upload_data as $upload) {
      $image = array(
       'parent_id'=>$category_data['id'],
       'type' => 'category',
       'description' => "",
       'path' => $upload['file_name'],
       'width'=>$upload['image_width'],
       'height'=>$upload['image_height']
      );
      $this->image->save($image);
     }
        
     $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Category is successfully added.');
    } else {
     $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Database error occured.Please contact your system administrator.');
    }
    
    redirect(site_url('categories'));
   } else {
    $data['error'] = $upload_data['error'];
   }
  }
  
  $content['content'] = $this->load->view('categories/add',array(),true);  
  $this->load_template($content);
 }
```

//Model

```
    function save(&$data, $id=false)
{
    if (!$id && !$this->exists(array('id' => $id, 'shop_id' => $data['shop_id']))) {
        if ($this->db->insert($this->table_name,$data)) {
            $data['id'] = $this->db->insert_id();
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        return $this->db->update($this->table_name,$data);
    }       
    return false;
}
```

//View

```
            <?php
            $this->lang->load('ps', 'english');
        ?>
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url() . "/dashboard";?>"><?php echo $this->lang->line('dashboard_label')?></a> <span class="divider"></span></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('categories');?>"><?php echo $this->lang->line('cat_list_label')?></a> <span class="divider"></span></li>
            <li><?php echo $this->lang->line('add_new_cat_button')?></li>
        </ul>

        <?php
            $attributes = array('id' => 'category-form','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data');
            echo form_open(site_url('categories/add'), $attributes);
        ?>
            <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
            <legend><?php echo $this->lang->line('cat_info_lable')?></legend>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><?php echo $this->lang->line('category_name_label')?>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltip-ps" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $this->lang->line('cat_name_tooltips')?>">
                                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign menu-icon'>
                                </a>
                            </label>
                            <?php echo form_input(array(
                                'name' => 'name',
                                'value' => '',
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'placeholder' => 'Category Name',
                                'id' => 'name'
                            )); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><?php echo $this->lang->line('ordering_label')?>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltip-ps" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $this->lang->line('cat_ordering_tooltips')?>">
                                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign menu-icon'>
                                </a>
                            </label>
                            <?php echo form_input(array(
                                'name' => 'ordering',
                                'value' => '',
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'placeholder' => 'Ordering',
                                'id' => 'ordering'
                            )); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><?php echo $this->lang->line('cat_photo_label')?>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltip-ps" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $this->lang->line('cat_photo_tooltips')?>">
                                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign menu-icon'>
                                </a>
                            </label>
                            <input class="btn" type="file" name="images1">
                        </div>  
                </div>

            </div>

            <hr/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $this->lang->line('save_button')?></button>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('categories');?>" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $this->lang->line('cancel_button')?></a>
        </form>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#category-form').validate({
                    rules:{
                        name:{
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 3,
                            remote: '<?php echo site_url("categories/exists/" . $this->shop->get_current_shop()->id);?>'
                        }
                    },
                    messages:{
                        name:{
                            required: "Please fill Category Name.",
                            minlength: "The length of Category Name must be greater than 4",
                            remote: "Category Name is already existed in the system."
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $(function () { $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so normal that works in localhost, but in server, directory permissions are so important and causes some problems.

In order to work in server, you should check the directory which you want to upload and make sure that this directory has necessary permissions like 777.
You need to debug errors for finding the problem.

Comment: Hello, i just set permission for the folder,

When i try to upload an image, a blank page is displayed with the message "string(10) "image/jpeg"

I believe it is the string from the mimes.php, but i don't know what is wrong..

P.S: -  i new a bit new to codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

I got into these kinds of issues many times.
Setting correct folder permissions in the remote server fixed the issue most of the times