# Codeigniter - File Upload and GoDaddy

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

For some reason this block of code works on my local machine but when I upload it to my GoDaddy server it doesn't work, it tells me "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.". This only happens when I try to upload csv and xlsx files, png and jpgs work no problem.

```
    $filename = "classlist_".date("YmdHis").".csv";
    $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH. '../uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx|xls|jpg|png|csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        print_r($this->upload);

        echo "error<br/>".$this->upload->display_errors();
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        exit;
```

Comment: Any error? Any notices, something?

Comment: Which Codeignitor version you are using in GoDaddy server?

Comment: @Naruto No notices or errors except the one that CI outputs

Comment: @Vidhi I'm using version 2.1.4

Comment: Check file permission and the upload folder permission.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10850763/2207961

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of server configuration for that specific filetype. That means that the filetype the server gives you for `xlsx` is not found in the `$mimes` variable in `mimes.php` file. The file `mimes.php` is found in `application/config/mimes.php`. Just print the `$_FILES` variable and add that mime you see there in $mimes variable.

Another method would be to force those mimes in .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx
AddType application/excel xls
AddType text/x-comma-separated-values csv
```

Comment: What does it print when you `print_r($_FILES);` after file `$this->upload->do_upload()`?

Comment: And of course it didn't worked as you have to specify the mimes. That is an example, NOT an working code!

Comment: Yes, I know that its not working code. I used the mime types printed when I did print_r($this->upload);

Comment: And what was the mimetype?

Comment: [xlsx] => Array
                (
                    [0] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                    [1] => application/zip
                )

Comment: It worked, stupid server took time to accept the .htaccess file, not sure why.