# Multiple file uploading with Codeigniter [Error : You did not select a file to upload.]

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files and i want to rename each file with current time. But when i am uploading files, I am getting an Error like

> You did not select a file to upload.

I really don't know where i went wrong..

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you..

Here is my controller:

```
public function upload_form()
{
    //load the helper
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $msg = array('msg' => "");
    if (isset($_FILES['upload_file'])) {
        $class = $this->input->post('class');
        $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
        $topic = $this->input->post('topic');

        $msg = array('msg' => "Upload success!");
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $files = $_FILES;
        $cpt = sizeof($_FILES['upload_file']['name']);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('upload_file')){
            $msg = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        }
        else{
            $data = array(
                'class' => $class,
                'subject' => $subject,
                'topic' => $topic,
                'file' => [
                    'file_name' => $_FILES['upload_file']['name']
                ]
            );
            $this->mongo_db->insert('file_upload', $data);
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i++) {
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $file_name = (microtime(true) * 1000);
            $_FILES['upload_file']['name'] = $file_name;
            $_FILES['upload_file']['type'] = $files['upload_file']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'] = $files['upload_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['upload_file']['error'] = $files['upload_file']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['upload_file']['size'] = $files['upload_file']['size'][$i];
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('worksheets/header');
    $this->load->view('worksheets/upload_form', $msg);
}
```

VIEW:

```
 <?php echo $msg; ?>
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('worksheets/upload_form/'); ?>
 <input type="file" name="upload_file[]" multiple="multiple" class="custom-     file-input" size="2000"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Fire" class="upload_submit"/>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Please post the view and entire control function.

Comment: Please take a look at my code.. @GopakumarGopalan

Comment: I don't understand what that for loop after `var_dump[$_FILES]` does...

Comment: That is nothing.. jus for my reference..

Answer (score 0):

try to print outcome of   $_FILES['upload_file']   and you will find the error .

Comment: It seems like files are not uploading, array (size=5)
  'name' => string '14235454000_1' (length=13)
  'type' => string 'a' (length=1)
  'tmp_name' => string 'C' (length=1)
  'error' => null
  'size' => null

Comment: In html tag should be like  <input type="file" name="upload_file[]">

Comment: "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Comment: But when i am changing config['allowed_types']= ' * ' ; , then its working.!!

Comment: Yes you need to define allowed types :) ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815208/codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allowed

Comment: You checked this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815208/codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allowed  ?   $config["allowed_types"] ="*";

Comment: yes. i set $config["allowed_types"] ="*";  when im uploading pdf file, file uploaded, but file in uploaded dir shows that its an unknown file type. i cant open it as a pdf file.. looks like .file extension

Answer (score 0):

Basically the Codeigniter File Upload Library is not meant for multiple file upload using `<input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple>`

You need multiple file inputs because it takes only the name of the input as a string.

Or you can extend the library for multiple file upload.

You can use this one > https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

Comment: but, when i use $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|jpg|png|jpeg|gif'; all the  files were getting uploaded.