# How to create custom mime type in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mime-types

I'm creating an upload form using CodeIgniter and I'm uploading a file with a .apk extension.
in My controller for time I have used * which is working but I want to allow the only apk files.

```
$config['allowed_types']        = '*';
```

can anyone help me to create custom mime type with sample code.

Comment: You can use the extension of the files you want to allow $config['allowed_types'] = 'apk';

Comment: it wont work I tried..

Comment: this will help [Add custom mime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815208/codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allowed)

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's not too late to answer this question!!

I was implementing a similar thing and ran into the same issue! After a bit of research on stackoverflow, I have a tried and tested answer.

As @phobia82 correctly said, this is an issue of mime types.
Having checked in some browsers and CodeIgniter 3.x, adding a custom mime type is what helps!
Also, worth noting is the fact that apk files are recognized with 2 mime types (from what I have tested)

```
| application/vnd.android.package-archive |
|-----------------------------------------|
| application/java-archive                |
```

So, goto `config/mimes.php` and add this to the array

```
'apk'   =>  array('application/vnd.android.package-archive','application/java-archive')
```

This was the reason why my upload failed. Codeigniter detected the APK archive as a java archive and the Apache server detected this as vnd.android.package-archive. Once you are done with this, you can use

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'apk';
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#setting-preferences-in-a-config-file), allowed_types refers to

> The mime types corresponding to the types of files you allow to be
>   uploaded. Usually the file extension can be used as the mime type. Can
>   be either an array or a pipe-separated string.

So you can use:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'apk';
```

If you want to be more specific and check the actual MIME type, for apk this is

```
application/vnd.android.package-archive
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'apk';
```

You can use this.

It will work fine.

thank you.

Comment: it won't work I have tried this it gives me an error "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Comment: then u can use javascript validation for that

Comment: This will not work if there is "apk" array in the core mlmes.php file, which there isn't. Suggesting javascript is not a good idea.