# CI File uploading gives file type error for rpt files

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload a Crystal Reports (.rpt) file using the following code:

```
$config=array(
 'upload_path'=>$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/assets/uploads/rpt/",
 'allowed_types'=>"rpt",
 'overwrite'  => TRUE,
 'file_name' =>$filename
);
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
if($this->upload->do_upload('rpt1'))
{
 echo "Done";
}
else
 echo $this->upload->display_errors();
```

But it returns:

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Then I tried to find out the uploaded file type:

```
print_r($_FILES['rpt1']['type']);
```

And it returns:

> application/octet-stream

I made the following update:

```
'allowed_types'=>"rpt|application/octet-stream",
```

But it didnt work and I still get the same error message.

I also added the following line to **application/config/mimes.php**

```
'rpt'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
```

What else I need to do in order to upload the .rpt file to the server?

Comment: They really using a pipe delimiter? Not arrays? `['allowed_types' => ['rpt' => 'application/octet-stream']]`... not familiar with CI.

Comment: @ficuscr This is just another option. We can directly create a configuration array and pass it or we can set individual key values too. i dont think this would affect

Comment: Seeing a lot on the topic... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815208/codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allowed Maybe just `"*"`? Can't really trust it anyway. Mime types that is.

Comment: @ficuscr Actually I need to allow only rpt file so dont want to use *. I had already gone through the article you have shared and in my problem description I have mentioned that I have already added the mime type.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the

> system/libraries/Upload.php

at line no. 454 (CI 3.x) and wrote the following line of code:

```
var_dump($this->file_type); die();
```

On execution, it returned

> text/plain

while using

```
print_r($_FILES['rpt1']['type']);
```

gave

> application/octet-stream

Now in the

> application/config/mimes.php

I wrote: `'rpt'   =>  'text/plain',`
and this time, things worked fine.